# When I enter the word "ma'am", the program doesn't count it as a palindrome

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

I have here a program that outputs the number of palindromes in a sentence. Case insensitive and ignores comma and periods when for instance the palindrome happens to be the last word in a sentence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char toUpper(char c) {
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        return c - 'a' + 'A';
    else
        return c;
}

char isLetter(char c) {
    return (toUpper(c) >= 'A' && toUpper(c) <= 'Z');
}

int findNextLetter(string& s, int start) {
    // find first letter at or after 'start'
    for (int i = start; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        if (isLetter(s[i])) return i;
    }
    return s.length();
}

int findNextPunct(string& s, int start) {
    // find first non-letter character at or after 'start'
    for (int i = start; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        if (!isLetter(s[i])) return i;
    }
    return s.length();
}

bool isPalindrome (const string& s, int start, int stop) {
    // look for palindrome in the range (start) to (stop - 1)
    for (int i = 0; i < (stop-start)/2; ++i) {
        if (toUpper(s[start + i]) != toUpper(s[stop - 1 - i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    string line;
    int counter=0;
    cout << "Please input a sentence." << endl;
    getline(cin, line);
    int wordStart = findNextLetter(line, 0);
    int wordEnd = findNextPunct(line, wordStart);
    while (wordStart != line.length()) {
        if (isPalindrome(line, wordStart, wordEnd))
            ++counter;
        wordStart = findNextLetter(line, wordEnd); // find start of next word
        wordEnd = findNextPunct(line, wordStart); // find end of next word
    }
    cout << "Number of Palindromes: " << counter << endl;
}
```

The program runs properly except when there is a word "ma'am". For example, when "Hello, ma'am! I'm Aya." is entered, the program just outputs 1, which means one palindrome: Aya. "ma'am" was not included because of the apostrophe.

I will be so happy if you show me a concrete code so it will be easy for me to figure out what to change. But still, I thank you for any kinds of help. :)

Comment: Well it splits the input into words by searching for punctuation. `'` is punctuation.

Comment: Do you not have access to a debugger that can trace through the code line by line? It's generally how problems get solved that cannot be seen in the source.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but your `toUpper` function is not
portable; there's no guarantee that alpha characters are contiguous
(they're not in the encodings I use most often), and there's even less 
guarantee that adding `'A' - 'a'` to a lower case character will give
the upper case.  Why not just use the standard `isupper`, which does
work (although if you use the single argument version, you'll have to
cast to `unsigned char` first).

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> wordStart = findNextLetter(line, wordEnd); // find start of next word
> wordEnd = findNextPunct(line, wordStart); // find end of next word
> ```

define a word as a run of letter characters.

> ```
> if (isPalindrome(line, wordStart, wordEnd))
> ```

is checking whether a word is a palindrome.  `"ma'am"` is not a word because it does not consist solely of letter characters.  `"ma'am"` is two words `"ma"` and `"am"` separated by a punctuation character, `"'"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already ignores commas and periods; extend it to include apostrophes, colons, semi-colons, and all other forms of punctuation.

Comment: colons and semi-colons do not form parts of words

Comment: Sez you.  If the requirement is that "Ma'am, I'm Adam" should be considered a palindrome, then the code should change accordingly.

Comment: Oh, fair enough. But then since the OP stated the requirement is "number of palindromes in a sentence" (implying multiple), if you're going to allow spanning words, then that gets a lot more complicated. Do whole words have to be considered? You end up taking all permutations of consecutive words and checking for palindromes on them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, colon is used in the IPA (Int'l phonetic alphabet) as a diacritical.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: It doesn't seem likely that the OP is looking for palindromes in IPA strings.

Comment: If I look at the code, I don't believe this is a person who is doing anything as complex as looking for multiple palindromes in a single sentence.  I'm guessing that it's one palindrome per sentence.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've been away for a while. I just want the program to count "ma'am" as a palindrome when "ma'am" is entered. If you run the code, it works just fine.

Comment: Does "works just fine" mean "I'm able to identify ma'am as a palindrome"?  If yes, why are you here?  If not, change your code to ignore apostophes and any other punctuation you need to and move on.